# Update Json string that stored on DB

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have DB table that one of his Column contain a JSON string like this:

```
{"freet1":"\u05d2'\u05dc\u05d0\u05e8\u05d8\u05d4 \u05de\u05d5\u05d3\u05d9\u05e2\u05d9\u05df - \u05de\u05d5\u05d3\u05d9\u05e2\u05d9\u05df - \u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8 \u05de\u05e9\u05dc\u05d5\u05d7\u05d9\u05dd - Ice Cream | Tinder","freet2":"5% \u05d4\u05e0\u05d7\u05d4","freet3":"\u05dc\u05de\u05d6\u05de\u05d9\u05e0\u05d9\u05dd \u05d3\u05e8\u05da \u05d4\u05d0\u05ea\u05e8","freet6":"\u05d4\u05d4\u05d6\u05de\u05e0\u05d4 \u05e9\u05dc\u05d9","freet4":"\u05d0\u05d9\u05df \u05d0\u05e4\u05e9\u05e8\u05d5\u05ea \u05dc\u05e9\u05e2\u05e8\u05da \u05d0\u05ea \u05d4\u05d4\u05d6\u05de\u05e0\u05d4 \u05de\u05db\u05d9\u05d5\u05d5\u05df \u05e9\u05d4\u05de\u05d5\u05e6\u05e8\u05d9\u05dd \u05e9\u05e7\u05d9\u05dc\u05d9\u05dd. \u05de\u05d9\u05e0\u05d9\u05de\u05d5\u05dd \u05de\u05e9\u05dc\u05d5\u05d7 45 \u05e9\"\u05d7","0":{"menu":"\u05d2\u05dc\u05d9\u05d3\u05d5\u05ea \u05e9\u05de\u05e0\u05ea","currentmenufile":"142525634133.JPG","data":[{"product":"\u05e9\u05d5\u05e7\u05d5\u05dc\u05d3 \u05de\u05e0\u05d8\u05d4","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425056679\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425056679\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05e9\u05d5\u05e7\u05d5\u05dc\u05d3 \u05d1\u05dc\u05d2\u05d9","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425056687\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425056687\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05e9\u05d5\u05e7\u05d5\u05dc\u05d3 \u05dc\u05d1\u05df","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425056695\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425056695\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05e9\u05d5\u05e7\u05d5\u05dc\u05d3 \u05e7\u05d9\u05e0\u05d3\u05e8","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425056702\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425056702\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05e9\u05d5\u05e7\u05d5\u05dc\u05d3 \u05ea\u05e4\u05d5\u05d6","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425056727\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425056727\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05e8\u05d9\u05d1\u05ea \u05d7\u05dc\u05d1","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425056815\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425056815\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05dc\u05d5\u05d8\u05d5\u05e1","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425056823\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425056823\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05e7\u05e4\u05d5\u05e6&#039;\u05d9\u05e0\u05d5","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425056830\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425056830\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05d5\u05d9\u05e1\u05e7\u05d9","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425056944\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425056944\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05d5\u05e0\u05d9\u05dc \u05e6\u05e8\u05e4\u05ea\u05d9","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425056953\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425056953\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05e2\u05d5\u05d2\u05d9\u05d5\u05ea \u05d0\u05d5\u05e8\u05d0\u05d5","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425056962\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425056962\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05de\u05e7\u05d5\u05e4\u05dc\u05ea","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425057129\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425057129\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05d5\u05e0\u05d9\u05dc \u05e7\u05dc\u05d9\u05e7","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425057136\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425057136\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05e4\u05e0\u05d9\u05e0\u05ea \u05d9\u05e2\u05e8","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425057143\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425057143\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05d8\u05d5\u05d5\u05d9\u05e7\u05e1","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425057472\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425057472\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05e2\u05d5\u05d2\u05ea \u05d2\u05d1\u05d9\u05e0\u05d4","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425057480\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425057480\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05ea\u05d5\u05ea \u05d1\u05e9\u05de\u05e0\u05ea","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425057487\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425057487\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05e4\u05e8\u05e8\u05d5 \u05e8\u05d5\u05e9\u05d4","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425058752\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425058752\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05e7\u05e8\u05de\u05dc \u05de\u05dc\u05d5\u05d7","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425058759\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425058759\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05d8\u05d5\u05e4\u05d9\u05e4\u05d9","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425058768\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425058768\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05d1\u05d0\u05d5\u05e0\u05d8\u05d9","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425060944\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425060944\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05e4\u05d9\u05e1\u05d8\u05d5\u05e7","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425060952\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425060952\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05d5\u05e4\u05dc \u05de\u05d9\u05d9\u05e4\u05dc","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425060960\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425060960\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05e0\u05d5\u05d8\u05dc\u05d4","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425063548\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425063548\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05dc\u05d5\u05d0\u05e7\u05e8","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425063559\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425063559\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05d7\u05dc\u05d1\u05d4","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425063567\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425063567\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05e7\u05e8\u05dd \u05e9\u05e0\u05d9\u05d8","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425256001\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425256001\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05d1\u05e0\u05e0\u05d4 \u05e4\u05e7\u05d0\u05df","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425410592\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425410592\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05e1\u05e0\u05d9\u05e7\u05e8\u05e1","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425256019\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425256019\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05d0\u05dc\u05e4\u05d7\u05d5\u05e8\u05e1","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425410136\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425410136\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05d8\u05d9\u05e8\u05de\u05d9\u05e1\u05d5","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425410144\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425410144\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05de\u05d2\u05e0\u05d5\u05dd","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425410156\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425410156\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05e8\u05e4\u05d0\u05dc\u05d5","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425410168\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425410168\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05d8\u05e2\u05de\u05d9","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425410185\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425410185\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05de\u05d9\u05dc\u05e7\u05d9","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425410193\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425410193\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05d9\u05d5\u05d2\u05d5\u05e8\u05d8 \u05d5\u05e4\u05d9\u05e8\u05d5\u05ea \u05d9\u05e2\u05e8","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425410202\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425410202\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"}],"menufile":"142525634133.JPG"},"1":{"menu":"\u05d2\u05dc\u05d9\u05d3\u05d5\u05ea \u05e1\u05d5\u05e8\u05d1\u05d4","currentmenufile":"142532108933.JPG","data":[{"product":"\u05dc\u05d9\u05de\u05d5\u05df","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425410247\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425410247\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05dc\u05d9\u05de\u05d5\u05e0\u05e2\u05e0\u05e2","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425410247\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425410247\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05ea\u05d5\u05ea \u05e9\u05d3\u05d4","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425410255\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425410255\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05e4\u05e1\u05d9\u05e4\u05dc\u05d5\u05e8\u05d4","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425410270\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425410270\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05de\u05e0\u05d2\u05d5","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425410270\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425410270\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05ea\u05e4\u05d5\u05d7 \u05d9\u05e8\u05d5\u05e7","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425410270\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425410270\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05e4\u05d9\u05e8\u05d5\u05ea \u05d9\u05e2\u05e8","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425410278\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425410278\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05e9\u05d5\u05e7\u05d5\u05dc\u05d3 \u05de\u05e8\u05d9\u05e8","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425410284\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425410284\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05e7\u05d5\u05e7\u05d5\u05e1","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425410290\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425410290\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05d3\u05d9\u05d0\u05d8 \u05e4\u05d9\u05e8\u05d5\u05ea","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"u","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425410297\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425410297\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"}],"menufile":"142532108933.JPG"},"2":{"menu":"\u05d2\u05dc\u05d9\u05d3\u05d5\u05ea \u05e1\u05d5\u05d9\u05d4","currentmenufile":"142532142833.JPG","data":[{"product":"\u05d1\u05d5\u05d8\u05e0\u05d9\u05dd","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425410304\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425410304\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05d7\u05dc\u05d1\u05d4","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425410310\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425410310\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05e4\u05d9\u05e1\u05d8\u05d5\u05e7","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425410321\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425410321\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05dc\u05d5\u05d8\u05d5\u05e1","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425410316\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425410316\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05d0\u05d2\u05d5\u05d6\u05d9 \u05dc\u05d5\u05d6","desc":"","price":"84","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05e7&quot;\u05d2","pgreen":"","unit":"k","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425410327\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425410327\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"}],"menufile":"142532142833.JPG"},"3":{"menu":"\u05e7\u05d9\u05e0\u05d5\u05d7\u05d9\u05dd","currentmenufile":"142564673833.JPG","data":[{"product":"\u05e7\u05e8\u05e4 \u05e6\u05e8\u05e4\u05ea\u05d9","desc":"","price":"18","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05d9\u05d7&#039;","pgreen":"","unit":"u","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425646773\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425646773\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05e7\u05e8\u05e4 + \u05d2\u05dc\u05d9\u05d3\u05d4 + \u05e7\u05e6\u05e4\u05ea","desc":"","price":"30","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05d9\u05d7&#039;","pgreen":"","unit":"u","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425646783\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425646783\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05d5\u05d5\u05e4\u05dc \u05d1\u05dc\u05d2\u05d9","desc":"+ 2 \u05db\u05d3\u05d5\u05e8\u05d9\u05dd + \u05e7\u05e6\u05e4\u05ea \u05d5\u05e1\u05d9\u05e8\u05d5\u05e3","price":"49","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05d9\u05d7&#039;","pgreen":"","unit":"u","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425646790\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425646790\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"},{"product":"\u05e1\u05d5\u05e4\u05dc\u05d4 \u05e9\u05d5\u05e7\u05d5\u05dc\u05d3 \u05d7\u05dd","desc":"+ \u05db\u05d3\u05d5\u05e8 \u05d2\u05dc\u05d9\u05d3\u05d4 + \u05e7\u05e6\u05e4\u05ea \u05d5\u05e1\u05d9\u05e8\u05d5\u05e3","price":"38","pgraysmall":"\u05dc\u05d9\u05d7&#039;","pgreen":"","unit":"u","pnew":"u","psale":"u","pactive":"y","currentfile":"1425796952\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG","file":"1425796952\u05ea\u05e4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d8.JPG"}],"menufile":"142564673833.JPG"}}
```

Is it possible to update only 1 "product" in this way? Because if I have more then 1,000 products the update is very slow (update all the string)

Better way then get the string by SQL Select the decode,change spesific values and then update the full string?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you exactly mean by Update 1 product?? Which is the product in here?? Could you please explain a bit.

Comment: That json should be a simple representation of structure, not a huge blob we can't easily read. This problem description is not very concise. Yes dataTables has server side handling and that is documented

Answer (score 0):

To update part of a JSON string stored in MySQL, you'll indeed need to retrieve, decode to an array/object, edit, encode as JSON, and store. It's time-consuming.

I'd recommend a change to your table schema. Not sure how it's set up right now, but instead of having one table with all of your info, you could have one table just for `Products`, another for `Orders`, another for `Customers`, etc.

So in your `Products` table, you'd have one row per product:

```
ID   |  NAME    | DESCRIPTION      |   PRICE
00123|  jacket  | gray wool jacket |   $4.99
```

Then in another table when you need to reference this product, you simply need to use the `ID` value. You can update the table rows for products *much* easier than editing their JSON.

Comment: This is the way that I'm always working. I thought maybe there is way to solve it without changing everything there

Comment: I wish, that would be nice. But tables are cheap, and storing JSON is okay for long-term stuff (things you won't need/want to change), but not for items that need updating.

Answer (score -1):

Regarding your first question, you cannot update only one product. There should be a row for each product, sounds like a terrible database design. It could make some sense if it was an static page but if you want to update or delete products it's gonna be really costly.

EDIT: Obviously when I said "you cannot update only one product" I meant to say that you must decode JSON string, modify the resulting array and encode it again to update a single product". It would have been more correct to say "you cannot update only one product without having to update the whole JSON array".